# SQL2012 crashes out of sql agent step creation when i attempt to set the step type to SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I am trying to set up a new SQL Agent job on a SQL2012 server. At the point of defining the job step type = SSIS package, the sql agent setup crashes and I get the following error:

> the type initializer for ‘’ threw an exception. (SQLManagerUI) Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (DTEParseMgd)

Other posts suggest that the only workaround is to install SQL2014 or 2016, or return to SQL2008. None of these options are possible for us.

We have to move away from SQL2008 for security reasons. We cannot move to SQL2014 because we use access adp project front ends which need the SQLOLEDB data provider which is obsolete in SQL2014.

Does anyone know if Microsoft have released a service patch for SQL2012 which fixes this issue for good?

Comment: Have you tried to create the step without the GUI? Just using code (you probably can copy the code of step creation from the sql2008 installation)

Comment: Yes, you should try with script rather then GUI, or you can try using Powershell to create the job, some help [here](http://sqlmag.com/powershell/use-powershell-create-agent-jobs)

Answer (score 2):

That memory error sounds like a server issue, but until you track that down, here's a workaround:  set the job step type to "Operating System (CmdExec)", and use `DTEXEC`, for example:

```
DTExec /DTS "\<ssisPkgName>" /DECRYPT <pkgPass> /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF
```

Note that if the SSIS package requires 32-BIT execution (true for exporting to Excel, for example), then use the DTEXEC utility in "Program Files (x86)" by fully qualifying it. Example, where the SQL Server application was installed on an "E:" drive, and where SQL Server 2014 is being used:

```
E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe" /DTS "\<ssisPkgName>" /DECRYPT <pkgPass> /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF
```

If your SSIS packages are in the file system (as ".dtsx" files), then replace "/DTS" with "/FILE".

If your SSIS packages were placed in SSISDB (using the "project deployment model", which is available starting with SQL Server 2012, instead of the older "package deployment model"), then replace "/DTS" with "/ISSERVER"

Lastly, consider your job step's "Run as": if your job step's "Run as" was already set to a proxy, then you already made that proxy "active" to the subsystem "SQL Server Integration Services Package". Now, to do command lines like the above, check that proxy's properties, and make sure it is also "active" to the subsystem "Operating system (CmdExec)".  (If you're not using a proxy, then you may need to add "Operating system (CmdExec)" for the SQL job agent... but a proxy is better for security:  why grant stuff to the agent, that you will only use in specific circumstances?)

(P.S. side benefit:  with the above, I find it easier to get *logging* from the SSIS package.)